# How to Copy a Value - x86 NASM Assembly

Tags: loops, assembly, copy, nasm

I am trying to figure out how to copy a value I am holding in a register for use immediately, and for use later in the program. I will be looping through code, and this value will need to be copied to another register for pushing it onto the stack, and then removal, copying, and repeating.

I know that the *mov* instruction moves a value into another register, but does the register from which the value is moved from able to retain the value?

For example:

```
mov eax, ebx
```

This would move ebx's value into eax, but would ebx still hold a value?

Any instruction that could help me do this is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> would ebx still hold a value?

Yes -- `mov` is really a copy, so the source retains its original value.